# read all files of assets folder and store them in a list variable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, assets

I want to fetch list of all images of /assets/images/wallpapers/ directory and store them in a List type variable to use them further, how can I do it in flutter?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of all assets by loading `AssetManifest.json` and filter by folder after that.

#### Example

```
  import 'dart:convert';

  Future _listAssets() async {
    // Load as String
    final manifestContent =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');

    // Decode to Map
    final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);

    // Filter by path
    final filtered = manifestMap.keys
        .where((path) => path.startsWith('assets/images/wallpapers/'))
        .toList();
    print(filtered);
  }
```

Comment: I will try it tonight, Thanks @YoBo :)